# Unit tests for managed package fail in target org after install

Tags: unit-test, managed-package, spring15

Some unit tests for our managed package fail in a target org when run after installation. The same tests run fine in our patch development org, and the package also installs without problems. It's only when the tests are run again after installation that the errors occur.

One specific error: `System.QueryException: No such column 'MiddleName' on entity 'Lead'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.`

I believe that message points to an API version issues, since the `MiddleName` field was moved from beta to GA recently (see https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Middle-Name-and-Suffix-Fields&language=en_US).

However, since neither our dev org nor the target org have the Middle name capability enabled, and none of our code directly references it, I don't understand where it could be coming from.

I'm still investigating but would appreciate input from anyone that has come across something similar.

Comment: You don't have any dynamic SOQLs on the lead object? Populated from a describe method?

Comment: Does it actually matter if your managed package test cases are failing beyond your packaging org? It shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: @greenstork: yes, there is dynamic SOQL. Looks like it is somehow picking up the MiddleName field from the fields map, even though it is not enabled for the org. I tried reproducing in anonymous APEX but could not. Maybe something related to the API version that my class is compiled with..

Comment: @DanielBallinger: yes, because these test failures prevent any other deployments in the target org

Comment: @JellevanGeuns if you specify runAllTests=false when deploying to production the managed package test cases won't be run.

Comment: This answer about when managed test failures matter might help convince you this isn't too big of a deal as @DanielBallinger suggests: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21507/how-to-handle-installed-managed-packages-failing-tests/21552#21552

Comment: @ca_peterson: I'm convinced, thank you both ;-) Still, all the test failures look bad so I'd like to clean them up somehow... I'll add an answer if I find the root cause