# Problems with new org in AppExchange class tests

Tags: appexchange, failing-tests

Hello there Stack Exchange, i've started working as a salesforce administrator&developer for a company where the old admin justleft a month ago. 
My experience is 3 months as a SF developer so i'm not an expert on the matter.

The main problem i have at the moment is that when i check how went the last imbound change, all test were succesful (55/55). But just the day i arrived i executed them just to check everything was allright and i found out that 16 test classes give error. 
When i tried to look at the code i found out they appear as hidden, because they were classes downloaded from the AppExchange that are not defined as global.

This classes are important since they comunicate ith Hubspot and and the other class that gives problems is related to DupperCatcher.
It just seems extrange that from 1 month to another where nobody changed nothing everything just started to fail.

Since i can't check the test code or modify it i just don't know how to react at all. I've already check if there exist any more recent versions of the API, apply them and I still can't get this thing fixed.

Some of the error codes I get, wich didnt helped mch for me:

```
System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject



System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, There's a problem with this country, even though it may appear correct. Please select a country from the list of valid countries.: [Country]
```

And other kind of errors.

Please does anyone know how can I fix this or some way to start advancing towards a solution?

It's really frustrating since i can't add new code to the org since i can't pass the test when I try to upload to production.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to investigate test failure per test failure. failing tests in managed packages shouldn't kill your deploy-ability. The country message may be related to standard country & state picklists. Is that feature enabled ? (old test code may use random country strings for country values).

Comment: Hi and thanks, i've checked the standard country & state and it's enabled.

Well i actually realized i could deploy directly from eclipse getting 0 errors sometimes but some other i got the same error than allways, thats kinda for weird for me. But whatshould i do if i cant even check the code on the test class, i'm kinda confused.
Anyway i think i should first correct the errors then starting deploy code to production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that test case failures in managed packages don't matter and can safely be ignored. See [How to handle installed Managed Packages failing tests?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/21552/102)

The tests in the managed package only need to pass when the managed package is being created. The creator of the managed package can't anticipate every possible environment it will be deployed into in the test cases.

For example, the managed package may use dynamic SOQL to work with an optional feature, such as revenue schedules. A test case in the packaging org will make assertions that this code works. While the packaging org will have this feature turned on, your org may not. The test case could be made to pass in your org, but it is of no real benefit to the creation of the managed package.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i coudnt pass through the test because there was 1 test class that wasnt managed that failed due to some changes I did on my code, once i solved that , the test went fine and I could upload aswell to production. Now i Only have to figure how to solve the problems with the managed classes and solve a http connection problem and i will have  full clean enviorment ready for new developments.

Thanks.