# Can FinancialForce affect my test coverage?

Tags: unit-test, deployment, ant, financialforce

I have FinancialForce installed in my SF instance, I want to deploy 3 new components from my sandbox environment 100% covered, but always I'm receiving the same deployment error related to Financial-force Triggers.

[image]

Is there any possible way to deploy my code or to cover those components?

Comment: Can you try with seeAllData= True in your test classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000044631&language=en_US

> When you run all test classes from UI then it will run the manage
>   package code tests and that contributes to code coverage. From
>   IDE/ANT(METADATA API), you don't see this behavior, it only runs the
>   test classes in your org namespace

Duplicate question:

[How to handle installed Managed Packages failing tests?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21507/how-to-handle-installed-managed-packages-failing-tests)

From ca_peterson:

Managed package tests are only run in the following scenarios:

- On package upload (only applicable to the package author)
- If explicitly selected to run (changing the namespace on the run dialog for Setup > Develop > Apex Test Execution, dev console, specific API calls to run them, like setting runTests in the metadata API deploy call).
- **[On metadata API deployments that have the runAllTests flag set to true][1]** (see the runAllTests description).

There have been situations in the past where managed tests run outside of these and all were deemed bugs and fixed. They do not *ever* run on change set deployments, although if there are managed triggers on objects your tests invoke those managed triggers will be run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I modified my build.xml file adding the runAllTest=true and also I added testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests" in my sd:deploy tag specifying  the classes that will run the test. I could deploy my classes and Trigger.