# unable to deploy my code in production getting dupecatcher testclass failed

Tags: deployment, error

I am trying to deploy a `Custome Fields` and `Apex Classes` (including test classes) from our sandbox to production. I used the `Outbound Change Set` and selected `Custom Tab`, `Custom Object`, and all `Custom Fields` in that object. the change set uploaded successfully but in inbound, I am getting this error:

> Your code coverage is 72%. You need at least 75% coverage to complete this deployment.

Comment: Please check your class coverage which you are deploying

Comment: Your title says something about a failing test, but it didn't make it into your post. Please clarify.

Comment: I dont think it should be an issue with test failures on a managed package. Its most likely the class coverage of the existing classes. Please review code coverage of the existing classes  in prodn and the classes you are deploying. You might have most likely forgotten to include the test class in your changeset

Comment: Thanks .. My problem is my apex classes and Test class  have  80% code coverage but we have  dupecather installed in our  org so that dupecather test class is not allowing to deploy

Comment: As far as i know, the test class of managed packages are not run during deployment. Refer this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21507/how-to-handle-installed-managed-packages-failing-tests

Comment: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: 
SetupOwnerId duplicates value on record with id: 0000: [] Stack Trace:testclass: line 9, column 1

This test class is dupecatcher test class which I   have no access to it

Answer (score 2):

Try setting your Apex Test Execution to run in succession rather than in parallel:  `Setup` > `Develop` > `Apex Test Execution`.  Select the <kbd>Options</kbd> button, and select `Disable Parallel Apex Testing`.

We made DupeCatcher.  Feel free to reach out to us directly and we’ll try to help:  support@symphonicsource.com